# RecyclerView - Iterator multiplying my itens

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I was trying to use the `foreach` to list my item, that is inside of my list called by *checklists* , but It got me an error called by **Concurrent Modification**. So, I found a solution like this:

```
//...
    List<Checklist> desc = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Iterator<Checklist> it = checklists.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                Checklist check = it.next();
                desc.add(new Checklist(check.getDescricao()));
                loadRecycler(desc);
            }
    //...
```

But now, I got an other problem: my items is getting duplicated every time that I open the screen. How can I solve this problem? Follow the whole code below:

> CheckListsFragment

```
public class ChecklistFragment extends Fragment {
    @BindView(R.id.checklist_rcv_itens)
    RecyclerView rvLista;
    @BindView(R.id.checklist_btn_novoitem)
    Button btnAddItem;
    int valor;
    BancoDAO bDAO;
    private Checklist checklist;
    private List<Checklist> checklists;
    private ListChecklistAdapter listChecklistAdapter;

    public ChecklistFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bDAO = new BancoDAO(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checklist, container, false);
        Log.i("LOG", "onCreate()");
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        checklist = new Checklist();
        checklists = bDAO.listAllItens();

        //It works, but multiply my items
        List<Checklist> desc = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Iterator<Checklist> it = checklists.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Checklist check = it.next();
            desc.add(new Checklist(check.getDescricao()));
            loadRecycler(desc);
        }

        /* It works, but multiply my items too
        for (Checklist checklist : new ArrayList<>(checklists)) {
            loadRecycler(checklists);
        } */

        return view;
    }

    private int cont() {
        return valor++;
    }

    //  add 1 item to the list
    @OnClick(R.id.checklist_btn_novoitem)
    void addItem() {
        checklists = new ArrayList<>();
        checklists.add(new Checklist("Teste " + (cont() + 1) + ""));
        bDAO.inserir(new Checklist("Teste " + (cont() + 1) + ""));
        loadRecycler(checklists);
        Helper.snackbarFast(getView(), "Item adicionado");
        return;    
    }

    private void loadRecycler(List<Checklist> lista) {
        if (listChecklistAdapter == null) {
            Log.i("LOG", "IF");

            listChecklistAdapter = new ListChecklistAdapter(getActivity(), lista);

            rvLista.setAdapter(listChecklistAdapter);
            rvLista.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
            rvLista.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), 1));
            return;
        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "ELSE");
            listChecklistAdapter.refreshData(lista);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using while instead of for loop?

Comment: No, I did not... How can I code this?

Comment: posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you remove this line `loadRecycler(desc);` from your loop like this:

```
    List<Checklist> desc = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Iterator<Checklist> it = checklists.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Checklist check = it.next();
        desc.add(new Checklist(check.getDescricao()));
    }

    loadRecycler(desc);
```

it looks like you are adding the list with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. And notice that I move the loadRecycler outside the loop. If you want to do some update inside the loop call notifyItemChanged(mPos).

```
    List<Checklist> desc = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Checklist> it = checklists.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Checklist check = it.next();
        desc.add(new Checklist(check.getDescricao()));
    }
    loadRecycler(desc);
```

And another hand you have to check what is the logic inside loadRecycler. The issue should be in how you are updating the adapter. Maybe you are adding the items instead of update it.

Comment: is the issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Resolved**
I just moved the loadRecycler() to out of the loop:

```
//   ...
        List<Checklist> desc = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Iterator<Checklist> it = checklists.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Checklist check = it.next();
            desc.add(new Checklist(check.getDescricao()));
            loadRecycler(desc);
        }
//   ...
```